# Why am I unable to "map" this mongoose collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to map a collection of user documents in mongoDB. Below is my code.

```
User.getUsers = function() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let users = await ValidUser.find()
            users.map(function(user) {
                return {
                    username: user.username,
                    email: user.email
                }
            })
            console.log(users)
            resolve(users)
        } catch {
            reject("404")
        }
    })
}
```

This code just logs the original stored data and doesn't "map" the array at all.

Comment: your map doesn't print anything, and the result isn't saved in any variable, so its expected to not see anything i think (map is like never happened), i think you want `users=users.map(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` function of an array returns a new array after applying the passed in mapping function to each element. If you assign it back into the `users` variable, that should correct the issue as the `console.log` and `Promise` resolve call will now be using the newly created array:

```js
users = users.map(function(user) {
    return {
        username: user.username,
        email: user.email
    }
})
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The map() method **creates a new array** populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array. If you want to use `map`, you'll need to assign the return array to `users`.

```
users = users.map(function(user) {
            return {
                username: user.username,
                email: user.email
            }
        })
```

The mapping you want to do can also be done through a [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) which is when you specify which fields you want to be returned by the database. In mongoose it might look like this:

```
let users = await ValidUser.find().select({ username: 1, email: 1, _id: 0 })
```